# Floated DIV width = 100% - widths of two other floated divs

Tags: css, html, layout, css-float

OK, so here is my problem,

I need to have four `DIV`s in one line. The First three are `float:left` and the fourth one is `float:right`. The container has a specified width.

I need the third `div` to fill all the space from the second `div` that is floated to the left, to the fourth `div` that is floated right.

**EDIT:** DIVs #1, #2 and #4 have dynamic width as well... They have a certain padding and the content defines the width.

Comment: Can we assume that div #1, #2 and #4 have specified widths (% or px)?

Comment: Show your code - what have you tried ?

Comment: Do you care what order your div's are in, for example, can div #3 appear before div #4 in the source code?

Comment: @MarcAudet Well, if it works, the order doesn't make a difference to me

Comment: You are defining in %?

Comment: @Arpit Sirvastava no, i ma not defining them at all

Answer (score 4):

Why not turn the question on its head, and establish how to create the layout you want- in which case, likely the simplest approach would be:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3GPL/)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>fit</div>
    <div class='cell'>fit</div>
    <div class='cell'>expand</div>
    <div class='cell'>fit</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%; /* <-- will make the divs align across the full browser width */
    height:50px;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:1%; /* <-- will make 1, 2, 4 only fit their content */
}
.cell:nth-child(3) {
    width:100%; /* <-- will make 3 expand to the remaining space */
}
```

Comment: While I generally would say that using tables for layouts is bad practice, the simplicity of this solution, and the fact that you didn't go the javascript approach right out of the gate is awesome. +1 from me!

Comment: @MatthewR. - totally agree on the avoidance of tables for layout purposes, in 99% of circumstances

Comment: Yep +1 from me for whole hearted  appreciation

Comment: Yeah this is probably the only time I have ever thought "Wow that is a great solution using tables!"

Comment: The most simple and straightforward solution to this problem

Comment: Using CSS tables is different from using HTML table tags, so the table-as-layout issue is not a factor here.  The advantage of this approach is that you maintain the order of the content and the child elements will remain on a single line regardless of the page width.  This is often a consideration in responsive designs.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution Using Floated Elements**

Here is one way of doing this using floats.

Arrange your HTML as follows:

```
<div class="panel-container">
    <div class="panel p1">Panel 1 - and a word</div>
    <div class="panel p2">Panel 2 - Done. </div>
    <div class="panel p4">Panel 4 - End!</div>
    <div class="panel p3">Panel 3</div>
</div>
```

and apply the following CSS:

```
.panel-container {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
.panel {
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 5px;
}
.p1 {
    float: left;
}
.p2 {
    float: left;
}
.p3 {
    background-color: tan;
    overflow: auto;
}
.p4 {
    float: right;
}
```

The trick is to place the floated elements (`.p1`, `.p2`. `.p4`) ahead of the in-flow content (`.p3`).

Use `overflow: auto` on the parent container to keep the floated child elements from affecting the layout outside of the parent element.

I added `overflow: auto` on `.p3` so that the padding gets included within the containing block.

See fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/9G8rT/

**Comments**

The one disadvantage of this approach is that the order of the content is altered, that is, `.p3` appears after `.p4` in the code order.

Another side effect, which may be desirable in a responsive design, is that the child elements will wrap onto 2 or more lines as the parent container width gets smaller.

If you need to retain the content order in the HTML code, the CSS table-cell solution is a good alterantive.

The table-cell solution will keep the child elements on a single line regardless of the width of the parent container.

One final advangtage of the floated element solution is that it is more backward compatible than a CSS table-cell solution, but as we move forward, this is becoming less
of a compelling argument.

Comment: problem with this approach is that content and the child elements will  not remain on a single line when more content is added it breaks into next line check out your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9G8rT/1/

Comment: The floated solution may not always be the best, see my comments above regarding the table-cell option.  Both options are appropriate for certain situations depending on the nature of the content as implied in your comments.